# dynamic random banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I'm trying to make a random preloaded banner with an unknown (but few) number of images.

I'm newbie on Javascript and jQuery but I almost got it working fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/kTS3t/1/

I suppose that there is something wrong because timing is not ok.
I split the first banner on javascript code because I want it to be shown with no delay.

Any clue whats wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Code (like on http://jsfiddle.net/kTS3t/1/):

CSS

```
#banner-governo {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
}
.banner-gov {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    display:none;    
}​
```

JS+JQUERY

```
$(window).load(function() {

var numItems = $('.banner-gov').length;
var i = 2;
var espera = 3000;

function bannerrand() {
    $('#banner-gov-1').fadeIn('medium', function() {
        $(this).delay(espera).fadeOut('medium');
    })

    while (i <= numItems) {
        var esperaItem = espera*i;
        $('#banner-gov-'+i).delay(esperaItem).fadeIn('medium', function() {
            $(this).delay(espera).fadeOut('medium', function(){
                if(i = numItems){
                    bannerrand();
                };
            });
        });

        i++;
    }
}
bannerrand();

}); //end $(window).load(function
```

HTML

```
<div id="banner-governo">
<div class="banner-gov" id="banner-gov-1">
    <img src="http://www.hospedagemdesitesgratis.org/img/hospedagem-gratis-html.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="banner-gov" id="banner-gov-2">
    <img src="http://apostilaria.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/javascript.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="banner-gov" id="banner-gov-3">
    <img src="http://otaqui.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/html5_vs_flash-300x100.png" />
</div>
</div>​
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it out. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kTS3t/4/

The idea is to cycle the images using `mod` operator and recall the animation function indefinitely using the callback function of `fadeOut`.

```
var numItems = $('.banner-gov').length;
var i = 2;
var espera = 3000;

function bannerrand() {


        //var esperaItem = espera*i;
        $('#banner-gov-'+(i% numItems + 1)).delay(espera).fadeIn('medium', function() {
            $(this).delay(espera).fadeOut('medium', function(){

                    bannerrand();

            });
        });

        i++;

}

    $('#banner-gov-1').fadeIn('medium', function() {
        $(this).delay(espera).fadeOut('medium', function(){

                    bannerrand();

            });

    })
```

Comment: This code worked fine, thank you very much! :)
I think that it is better with no delay between banners, so I did another modification and it became perfect (removed delay on fadein) http://jsfiddle.net/kTS3t/10/

I just could not understand what you mean with mod operator and this code: +(i% numItems + 1) !

Comment: @LuAmbros Yes change the delay to suit your needs. The mod operator `%`reutrns the remainder after `i` is divided by `numItems`. So it always return a number between `0` and `numItems - 1`.

Comment: @LuAmbros By the way the display order now is not random but in sequential order. You can use `Math.random()` to randomize the display though. Replace  `i` to something like `Math.floor((Math.random()*100))` would do.

Comment: Thank your for your tips and help! By now the random is coming from wordpress query on my case with "'orderby' => 'rand'" code :)